# python 3.7 and ldap3 reading group membership

Tags: python-3.7, ldap3

I am using Python 3.7 and ldap3.  I can make a connection and retrieve a list of the groups in which I am interested.  I am having trouble getting group members though.

```
server = Server('ldaps.ad.company.com', use_ssl=True, get_info=ALL)
with Connection(server, 'mydomain\\ldapUser', '******', auto_bind=True) as conn:

    base = "OU=AccountGroups,OU=UsersAndGroups,OU=WidgetDepartment," \
           + "OU=LocalLocation,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com"

    criteria = """(
        &(objectClass=group)
         (
            |(sAMAccountName=grp-*widgets*)
             (sAMAccountName=grp-oldWidgets)
         )
    )"""

    attributes = ['sAMAccountName', 'distinguishedName']
    conn.search(base, criteria, attributes=attributes)
    groups = conn.entries
```

At this point `groups` contains all the groups I want.  I want to itterate over the groups to collect the members.

```
    for group in groups:
        # print(cn)

        criteria = f"""
            (&
                (objectClass=person)
                (memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={group.distinguishedName})
            )
        """
        # criteria = f"""
        #    (&
        #       (objectClass=person)
        #        (memberof={group.distinguishedName})
        #    )
        # """

        attributes = ['displayName', 'sAMAccountName', 'mail']
        conn.search(base, criteria, attributes=attributes)
        people = conn.entries
```

I *know* there are people in the groups but `people` is always an empty list.  It doesn't matter if I do a recirsive search or not.

What am I missing?

**Edit**

There is a longer backstory to this question that is too long to go into.  I have a theory about this particular issue though. I was running out of time and switched to a different python LDAP library -- which is working.  I *think* the issue with this question might be that I "formated" the query over multiple lines. The new ldap lib (`python-ldap`) complained and I stripped out the newlines and it just worked.  I have not had time to go back and test that theory with `ldap3`.

Answer (score 2):

`people` is overwritten in each iteration of your loop over groups.
Maybe the search result for the last `group` entry in `groups` is just empty.

You should initialise an empty list outside of your loop and extend it with your results:

```
people = []
for group in groups:
    ...
    conn.search(...)
    people.extend(conn.entries)
```

Another note about your code snippet above. When combining objectClass definitions with attribute definitions in your search filter you may consider using the `Reader` class which will combine those internally.

Furthermore I would like to point out that I've created an object relational mapper where you can simply define your queries using declarative python syntax, e.g.:

```
from ldap3_orm import ObjectDef, Reader
from ldap3_orm.config import config
from ldap3_orm.connection import conn

PersonDef = ObjectDef("person", conn)
r = Reader(conn, PersonDef, config.base_dn, PersonDef.memberof == group.distinguishedName)
r.search()
```

ldap3-orm documentation can be found at http://code.bsm-felder.de/doc/ldap3-orm